# How to send windows logs to LogRhythm DP using Microsoft Sysmon?

Tags: windows, logging, soc

I want to transfer windows logs to LogRhythm SIEM, but I can't use logRhythm agent because it uses the PORT 445 which I don't want to open.
I want to use Microsoft Sysmon. How to use it and which PORT it will use and is it secure?

I'm expecting a secure way to send Win Logs to LogRhythm SIEM

Comment: Sysmon is a system monitoring agent, not a log forwarding component

Comment: so how to send logs collected by Sysmon to LogRhythm?

Comment: Optimal solution depends on _why_ you won't give LogRhytm access to fetch the events over RPC. What are you trying to defend against?

Comment: It's in the organisation's policies. Is there a way to transfer windows logs securely to logRhythm without using the port 445?

Comment: my own preference would be to use [Windows' built-in event forwarding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/operating-system-security/device-management/use-windows-event-forwarding-to-assist-in-intrusion-detection) to centralize the events on a single box and the have LogRhythm collect them from that one box - then you only need a policy exception for 1 box instead of all of them :)

Comment: you mean using a centralized server with WEF service. Which protocol and port it will use?

Comment: WEF uses WinRM for transport, so that'll be HTTP/HTTPS (winrm listener defaults to port 5985/5986 on Windows)